# Graph with no triangles and with two non-neighbours vertices having exactly $b$ common neighbours is regular

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I have encountered the following problem:

If $\Gamma$ is a graph on at least $3$ vertices and containing no triangles and with two non-neighbours vertices having exactly $b \geq 2$ common neighbours then $\Gamma$ is $k$-regular.

Edit: This is my worked realised so far:

The idea is basically to take to consider two vertices , and show that if they are not neighbours then the numbers of vertices that are nb to  but not to  is the same as the numbers of vertices that are nb to  but not to . Then do the same for , being neighbours.

Case i: If , are not nb then let $_1$ be nb of  but not , so there exists a set $Z_1$ of size  of vertices nb to  and . They clearly can't be nb to . I guess that the idea is to repeat this for all $z_i$ nb of  but of  but how can I make sure that the union of all this $Z_i$ is of the same as the nb of ?

Comment: The idea is basically to take to consider two vertices $x,y$ and show that if they are not neighbours then the numbers of vertices that are nb to  $x$ but not to $y$ is the same as the numbers of vertices that are nb to  $y$ but not to $x$. Then do the same for $x,y$ neighbours.

Comment: I also see that if $x,y$ are not nb then let $z_1$ be nb of $x$ but not $y$, so there exists a set $Z_1$ of size $b$ of vertices nb to $z$ and $y$. They clearly can't be nb to $x$. I guess that the idea is to repeat this for all $z_i$ nb of $x$ but of $y$ but how can I make sure that the union of all this $Z_i$ is of the same as the nb of $x$?

Comment: In the case that $x,y$ are nb wouldn't the number of edges from $x_1 \in X$ to $Y$ be $b$?